# Gaussian Process Regression: Mapping a input to a time series

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, gaussian, gpflow

First, I would like to describe what I am trying to achieve:
My input X consists of 2 values and output Y consists of 2 lists with different lengths:

```
list_1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 10, 11, 11, 11, 14, 14, 15, 15, 20, 20, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 22, 22, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 22, 22, 22, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
list_2 =[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 20, 20, 25, 25, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 27, 27, 7, 7, 7, 7, 15, 15, 15, 22, 22, 22, 27, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 

X= [-28,32] 
Y= [list_1,list_2]
```

In most of cases, regression problem maps an input x to a single output y. However in my case, I need to map an input x to a time series y. I am trying to implement this in python using gpflow. I would like to have your opinions, whether the choice of GPR is appropriate for this case and if someone has already done similiar tasks, could you give me some introduction?

Comment: I cannot think of any (reasonably simple) approaches for directly modelling Y = f(X) where elements in Y are lists of arbitrary length (and different for each element in X). It may help to add a bit more context of what you want to do with this for people to be able to better help you!

Comment: @STJ I am trying to implement this GPR model from the paper: https://www.ias.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/uploads/Site/EditPublication/TaseOsa17.pdf . As you can see in the page 684, the authors take the initial position of the surgical instrument as the input and estimate the correspond trajectory values including the force value. However, as Fabricio stated, a normal GPR gives a distribution over samples from a function. Here, in this paper, the data set is defined as X=[initial position, initial position,  ...] and Y= [state of the system_1, state of the system_2, ...].

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly apply vanilla GPs to your problem in the way you formulated it.

A GP gives you a distribution over possible functions, conditioned on samples from one stochastic function. If I understand your setting correctly you have a collection of functions (Time series) and want to learn the underlying dynamics of those functions when conditioning on your X (the [-28, 32]).

Let's reframe your problem setting:

```
list_1 = [....]
list_2 = [....]
...

k = [-28, 32, ...]

X1 = np.arange(0, len(list_1))
Y1 = list_1

X2 = np.arange(0, len(list_2))
Y2 = list_2
...
```

In the framework of GPs I would say you want to learn a kernel that depends on your k.
Then, given that Kernel, you have a standard GP where the `x`s are the time indexes  and the `y=f(x)+noise` are the time series values. For each k You have some training data you condition on (that is e.g. `(X1, Y1)`) and want to predict the values f(x) for some other time points (maybe inbetween your x, or in the future for forecasting).

So what you could do is try something like a DeepKernel, where a neural network (or some other function) predicts the Kernel given k(see for example [1]). You could train it via maximizing the marginal likelihood of your training data in gpflow. There are probably some other, more data efficient, methods for learning a kernel, but you'll have to research that.

Alternatively, I've recently seen a few papers about so-called 'Neural Processes', where they have a similar setting: https://github.com/deepmind/neural-processes
Here the stochastic processes are predicted exclusively with Neural Networks, and not GPs.

Note however that both methods would probably require quite a bit of data.

[1] Calandra, Roberto, et al. "Manifold Gaussian processes for regression." 2016 International Joint Conference on Neural Networks (IJCNN). IEEE, 2016. 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5876